# override doGet in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to make a servlet, and trying to override my `doGet` method. There is an error in the `@Override doGet`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
```

It is under processRequest the error comes. The concrete error message is:

```
The method processRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is undefined for the type 
CookieUsageServlet
```

Does anybody know why I get this error?

```
   package ExamplePackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/CookieUsageServlet")
public class CookieUsageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Cookie cookie = getCookie(request, response);
        printResponse(response, cookie);
    }


    private Cookie getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie cookie = null;
        Cookie[] cookiesArray = request.getCookies();
        if(cookiesArray != null) {
            for(int x = 0; x < cookiesArray.length; x++) {
                if(cookiesArray[x].getName().equals("test_cookie")) cookie = cookiesArray[x];
            }
        }
        if(cookie != null) {
            System.out.println("cookie retrieved");
        } else {
            int timeToExpireCookie = new Integer(getServletContext().getInitParameter("time-to-expire-cookie")).intValue();
            cookie = new Cookie("test_cookie", Long.toString(new Date().getTime()));
            cookie.setMaxAge(timeToExpireCookie);
            cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath()); // Sti til login
            System.out.println("Cookie created...");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
        return cookie;
    }
    private void printResponse(HttpServletResponse response, Cookie cookie) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        printWriter.println("<html>");
        printWriter.println("<head><title>Cookie In JAVA servlet</title></head>");
        printWriter.println("<body>");
        printWriter.println("<cookie name: " + cookie.getName() + "<br>");
        printWriter.println("<cookie value: " + cookie.getValue() + "<br>");
        printWriter.println("<time to expire cookie in seconds: " + cookie.getMaxAge() + "<br>");
        printWriter.println("</body>");
        printWriter.println("</html>");


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? It says that you have no processRequest() method in your servlet. Do you have one? No you don't. You can't call a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: I just edited the code. Instead of processRequest() I put in doPost() like in the video. When I run the servlet I get the error: HTTP Status 500 - null

Comment: exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
 java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:660)
 ExamplePackage.CookieUsageServlet.getCookie(CookieUsageServlet.java:39)
 ExamplePackage.CookieUsageServlet.doPost(CookieUsageServlet.java:23)
 ExamplePackage.CookieUsageServlet.doGet(CookieUsageServlet.java:19)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: Have you read the stack trace? It says that null is passed to the Integer constructor called at line 39 of your class. So `getServletContext().getInitParameter("time-to-expire-cookie")` returns null. Do you see a pattern in my comments? Reading the error messages helps in finding the problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes I understand what you mean. I am just learning, so it is hard for me to read all the errors. Okay when I add:

 <context-param>
    <param-name>time-to-expire-cookie</param-name>
    <param-value>20</param-value>
  </context-param>

I get a blank screen :-/

Comment: I understand it's hard at the beginning. But not trying won't make it easier. Take time to read, try and practice.

Comment: But how do you see that it is in lien 39 there is an error. I see the numbers 417, 23, 23, 19 etc. That is what confuse me

Comment: look in the stack trace for the line number from your class . `ExamplePackage.CookieUsageServlet.getCookie(CookieUsageServlet.java:39)`

Comment: ops it works now. I expected a message on the screen, but in the bottom console in Eclipse, it says cookie created

Comment: You read a stack trace from the beginning. You first have the exception type and message, and the location where it's thrown: Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417) . This method is called by the Integer constructor, in Integer.java:660. This constructor is called by CookieUsageServlet.getCookie(CookieUsageServlet.java:39). And this is your own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the exception `getServletContext().getInitParameter("time-to-expire-cookie")` value is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
package ExamplePackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/CookieUsageServlet")
public class CookieUsageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Cookie cookie = getCookie(request, response);
        printResponse(response, cookie);
    }


    private Cookie getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie cookie = null;
        Cookie[] cookiesArray = request.getCookies();
        if(cookiesArray != null) {
            for(int x = 0; x < cookiesArray.length; x++) {
                if(cookiesArray[x].getName().equals("test_cookie")) cookie = cookiesArray[x];
            }
        }
        if(cookie != null) {
            System.out.println("cookie retrieved");
        } else {
            int timeToExpireCookie = new Integer(getServletContext().getInitParameter("time-to-expire-cookie")).intValue();
            cookie = new Cookie("test_cookie", Long.toString(new Date().getTime()));
            cookie.setMaxAge(timeToExpireCookie);
            cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath()); // Sti til login
            System.out.println("Cookie created...");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
        return cookie;
    }
    private void printResponse(HttpServletResponse response, Cookie cookie) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        printWriter.println("<html>");
        printWriter.println("<head><title>Cookie In JAVA servlet</title></head>");
        printWriter.println("<body>");
        printWriter.println("<cookie name: " + cookie.getName() + "<br>");
        printWriter.println("<cookie value: " + cookie.getValue() + "<br>");
        printWriter.println("<time to expire cookie in seconds: " + cookie.getMaxAge() + "<br>");
        printWriter.println("</body>");
        printWriter.println("</html>");


    }

}
```

Web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>time-to-expire-cookie</param-name>
        <param-value>20</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Comment: Thans a lot everybody for the help